# Generate Database menu item in Entity Modeler only brings up Save to DDL Wizard

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database

I'm using VS2K13.3, and have a connection setup in my Entity Data Model (model first) to an Azure database.

When I right click on the surface of the modeler and select Generate Database, all I get is a dialog to save the model to a DDL script in my project. I don't get a wizard to publish the model and generate a database on an external database (for instance Azure).

Online tutorials show a different result. Any idea why this might be happening?

For example when reading these instructions, the dialog that I get is not what's described within this linke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456815(v=vs.100).aspx

I reread this and apparently it's working as described. How then do you get the DDL executed in Azure SQL?